# Titanium_iphone contacts

Tags: iphone, titanium, contacts

I am trying to list contacts with Titanium. WOrks on android device, but on iphone simulator doesn't return anything.

```
var contacts= Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople();
alert("contacts.length");
```

returns 0. I am not sure what am i missing here.

Comment: iPhone need contacts to be authorised first. Whereas in android many time it don't need authorisation but for safer side always try to authorise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have contacts created on your iOS simulator:

- Use Home button (CMD+Shift+H) to go to dashboard.
- Open up Contacts app
- Create few contacts which you want to retrieve in your app.

Also before you call `Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople()` you have to request authorisation to contact list. Try code below:

```
function processContacts() {
    Ti.API.info('authorized');
    var contacts = Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople();
    Ti.API.info(contacts.length);
}

if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_AUTHORIZED){
    processContacts();
} else if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_UNKNOWN){
    Ti.Contacts.requestAuthorization(function(e){
        if (e.success) {
            processContacts();
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('disallowed');
        }
    });
} else {
    Ti.API.info('disallowed');
}
```

One last thing, in your code you wrote: `alert("contacts.length")` which will always display dialog view with "contacts.length" as a string, not value. To call it properly you should write: `alert(contacts.length)` without double quotes.